# Before update trigger, update column for each update

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers

I created before update trigger for custom APEX authentication. Trigger should convert password in MD5 when password is updated, but I get new password for every update, eg. I update username only, I also get new random password.

```
create or replace TRIGGER bu_users
  BEFORE UPDATE ON USERS
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :NEW.username := upper(:NEW.username);

    IF :NEW.password IS NOT NULL THEN
      :NEW.password := fn_hash(:NEW.password);
    ELSE
      :NEW.password := :OLD.password;
    END IF;  
END;
```

fn_hash:

```
 FUNCTION fn_hash (p_text IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
    l_results VARCHAR2(4000);
  BEGIN
    SELECT standard_hash(p_text, 'MD5')
      INTO l_results
      FROM DUAL;

    RETURN l_results;
  END fn_hash;
```

Comment: What does this do: fn_hash ?

Comment: Convert string to MD5

Comment: Is it created by you or ? If yes can we see it ?

Comment: This function select standard_hash

Comment: OK, can we see the code ? How can we be shure that your problem is not there ?

Comment: I added function

Comment: Can you check what would be in the password column if there is no if then else part ?

Comment: Same without else part, password is changed, but when I disabled whole trigger work normal but, without hashing.

Comment: The `ELSE` part seems pretty useless.

Comment: Unrelated, but: the body your fn_hash() function can be simplified to `return standard_hash(p_text, 'MD5');` no need for a SELECT or a variable.

Comment: I followed this steps, you can see trigger here: https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/custom-authentication-and-authorization-using-built-in-apex-access-control-a-how-to

Comment: All looks ok to me. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=25be56488a2224301b22487b11abaa51 please add your example, how you see it , that gives you bad results...

Comment: when I change username, password is also changed / Kada promenim bilo koju kolonu, automatski mi se promeni i password i ne mogu se ulogovati.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ce6217cd7fbd70d2f222743539b733b7

Comment: @Goku, I have added my answer. Valjda će biti od pomoći...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
create or replace TRIGGER bu_users
  BEFORE UPDATE 
  ON USERS
  FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    :NEW.username := upper(:NEW.username);

    IF :NEW.password != :OLD.PASSWORD THEN
      :new.password := fn_hash(:NEW.password);
    ELSE
      :NEW.password := :OLD.password;
    END IF;  
    
END;
/
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e039005c26b80e495792c2b9c76cfe80)